# Cypress TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a Cypress project with TypeScript support using the Cucumber Preprocessor and all of a sudden it started to throw the below exception:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')
```

Some times it works when I change to a different workspace but again this error is reproducing when I open the Cypress runner itself and even when executing in Jenkins too.

**Cypress Runner:** (v8.4.0)

[image: Cypress Runner]

**Jenkins Console:** (v8.7.0)

```
The function exported by the plugins file threw an error.

We invoked the function exported by `C:\Jenkins\workspace\ABC\cypress\plugins\index.js`, but it threw an error.

 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uid')
    at Object.statSync (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:303:17)
    at isDirectory (C:\Jenkins\workspace\ABC\ui\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:22:23)
    at loadNodeModulesSync (C:\Jenkins\workspace\ABC\ui\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:191:17)
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (C:\Jenkins\workspace\ABC\ui\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:98:17)
    at module.exports (C:\Jenkins\workspace\ABC\ui\cypress\plugins\index.js:15:25)
    at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:90:12
    at tryCatcher (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:39:29)
    at load (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:87:7)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\child\run_plugins.js:198:5)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\plugins\util.js:19:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at process.emit (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:495:21)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:910:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**plugins/index.js**

```
const resolve = require('resolve');
const cucumber = require("cypress-cucumber-preprocessor").default;
const cypressBrowserify = require("@cypress/browserify-preprocessor");
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const db = require('../../cypress.json')
var mssql = require('mssql');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const allureWriter = require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  
  const options = {
    ...cypressBrowserify.defaultOptions,
    typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {project:  config.projectRoot}),
  };  
  
  on("file:preprocessor", cucumber(options));

  on('task', {
    'createMySQLConnection'(query) {
      var value = mysqlDB(query)
      return value
    }
  });

  function mysqlDB(query) {
    var dbenv = config.env.configFile
    var connection="";
    if(dbenv=="qa"){
      connection = mysql.createConnection(db.qa)
    }
    else if(dbenv=="stg"){
      connection = mysql.createConnection(db.stg)
    }
    else if(dbenv=="stg2"){
      connection = mysql.createConnection(db.stg2)
    }
    connection.connect()
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error)
        }
        connection.end()
        return resolve(results)
  
      })
    })
  }

  on('task', {
    'createMSSQLConnection'(query) {
      return mssqlDB(query)
    }
  });


 async function mssqlDB(query){
   const connection = await mssql.connect(db.env);
   var sqlServerRequest = new mssql.Request(connection);
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sqlServerRequest.query(query, (error, recordset) => {
      mssql.close(); 
      if(error){
      reject (error)
      }
      else{
        resolve (recordset)
      }
    }) 
  })
 };
 
  allureWriter(on, config);
  const file = config.env.configFile || 'stg2';
  const pathToConfigFile = path.resolve('cypress/config', `${file}.json`);
  return config,fs.readJson(pathToConfigFile);
  
}
```

**support/index.ts**

```
import './commands';
import '@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/reporter';
import 'cypress-xpath';
import 'cypress-plugin-tab';   

Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  cy.log(`Uncaught Exception: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your index.js file from the plugins folder where the error seems to occur?

Comment: @SebastianoVierk I have added the index.js and index.ts files

Comment: Where is 'uid' used in your project? The first assumption would be that you have something like "variable.uid" and the "variable" is undefined.

Comment: No, the uid is not used in anywhere in the project, I have tested this in project search as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried many things like cleaning the cache, analyzing the index.js file but the below one fixed issue.

Uninstall the Cypress from the machine and installed with the Cypress version 8.5.0 and everything started to work fine

```
npm install cypress@8.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Strange behavior anyway, because it happens when I try to start the test on my local machine. There was no error when tests were started using a git actions workflow. For me, the solution was the comment of "aidanhyland" from here:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/19674#issuecomment-1012212527
The issue has nothing to do with the use or not of "uid" in you code. The issue is in the cucumber dependency and how they are solved.